# How do I stop my modal from closing when I click anywhere inside it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog

I have made a modal in a component, the data works fine, it's dynamic which is perfect. Problem is, when I open it, it seems that whenever I click anywhere inside the modal, it closes it again.

The modal is managed using useState hook. I think the problem lies in my onClick calls further down. Any advise please?

```js
const LeaveRequestsUnits = () => {
  let [data, setData] = useState([]);
  let [modalState, setModalState] = useState(false);
  let modalOnOff = () => {
    setModalState(!modalState);
  };
  let [selectedUnit, setSelectedUnit] = useState('');
  let updateSelectedUnit = (item) => {
    setSelectedUnit(item);
    
      const getLeaveUnits = data.map((item) => {


// fct to update the modalState and display-block the modal
    const openModal = (item) => {
      updateSelectedUnit(item);
      modalOnOff();
      $('.modalBackground').css('display', 'block');
    };

    const modal = () => {
      return (
        <div>
          <p>{selectedUnit.note}</p>
          <p>{selectedUnit.start}</p>

          <p>{selectedUnit.end}</p>
          <a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
          <h1>Close</h1>
        </div>
      );
    };

    // display:none the modal if the modalState is false
    if (!modalState) {
      $('.modalBackground').css('display', 'none');
    } 


    if (item.end >= today && item.approved !== false) {
      return (
        <div
          className={unitColour}
          key={item.reqID}
          onClick={() => openModal(item)}
        >
          <div className='unitLeft'>
            <img src={statusIcon} alt='Status Icon' id='statusIcon' />
          </div>

          <div className='unitMiddle'>
            <p id='unitLeaveType'>{leaveTypeName}</p>
            <p id='unitDate'>{startEndDate(item.start, item.end)}</p>
          </div>

          <div className='unitDivider'></div>

          <div className='unitRight'>
            <p id='unitDuration'>
              {convertTimestamp(item.duration, item.type)}
            </p>
          </div>
          {/* modal */}
          <div className={`modalBackground modalShowing-${modalState}`}>
            {modal()}
          </div>
          {/* end modal */}
        </div>
      );
    }
  });

  return <div className='requestsContainer
```

CSS below:

```css
.modalBackground {
  display: none;
  z-index: 10000;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: black;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: auto;
}

.modalShowing-true {
  /* display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.3; */
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Comment: put a click listener on the modal component where you call `stopPropagation()` aka on the topmost element of your modal `<div onClick={this.cancelClose}>` where that function looks like this `cancelClose(event) { event.stopPropagation() }`

Comment: Other notes. Don't use jquery here to change the classes, jquery and react are both trying to manipulate the DOM. It's better to just let one handle that for you so you have less things to test.

Comment: @JohnRuddell Thank you John. That worked like a charm. Annoyingly, I learn this in a recent React course, but forgot about the stopPropagation! Your help is greatly appreciated - I will stop being lazy and take on your advice regarding the jquery vs react both using the DOM. I cannot mark you comment as an answer, but please feel free to do so and I will mark it as such. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define the modal component, you need to tell it to prevent clicks on it from bubbling up to the parent elements click listener that will try to close the modal.

```
const cancelClick = useEffect( (event) => {
  event && event.stopPropagation();
}, []) // only need to create this function once

const modal = () => {
  return (
    <div onClick={cancelClick}>
      <p>{selectedUnit.note}</p>
      <p>{selectedUnit.start}</p>

      <p>{selectedUnit.end}</p>
      <a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
      <h1>Close</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I would HIGHLY recommend you stop using jquery here as well. In this component its a super easy change, just remove the jquery calls to change the display css property on the backdrop and instead use the state variable to control showing that.

```
<div className={`modalBackground${!!modalState ? ' open' : ''}`}>
  {modal()}
</div>
```

and then you can clean up the css for it. I dropped the `display: none;` style and went with `transform: scale(0);`. This gives more flexibility in how you decide how you want to show the modal (fade in would do nicely).

```
.modalBackground {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10vh;
  z-index: 10000;
  overflow: hidden;

  width: 80vw;
  height: 250px;

  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
  background-color: white;
  color: black;

  border-radius: 15px;
  cursor: auto;

  /* here you can add a transition on both opacity and scale to make the modal animate in. */
}

.modalBackground.open {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

Comment: Strangely, using your first method in your note before, the modal is now still closing when i click anywhere in the lower half of the modal. No idea what is causing this. Secondly, I have just implemented your new code in your answer, but now the modal's information is not opening into a modal, instead, it is showing in the unit (the unit is the div that is pressed on to open the modal).

Comment: So I figured there was as space needed here for the modal to show up: <div className={`modalBackground[SPAC HERE]${!!modalState ? 'open' : ''}`}> - so that's that sorted, however, now I'm using the full way you said in your answer, it's now closing when I click anywhere inside the modal. I think it's now missing the stopPropagation method somehow.

Comment: sorry, i missed the space. I intentionally left the space out where you added it because i didn't want the extra space there all the time. Should have put it in the `'open'` part. i'll update the answer rn

Comment: OK, all points now fixed, a few adjustments i had to made to your code, the final one re. the stopPropagation was because the cancelClick function had to be called on the modal div in the returned render, and not in the modal content variable, otherwise the modal has to be already open in order to be fired. Anyway - your solution has helped massively. Thank you again.

Comment: Ok great! I was just writing up a codesandbox to give a live demo of it to help with the confusion... but sounds like its not needed! Good luck with your project and feel free to reach out with more issues :) Happy coding!